# wp_enqueue_style() breaks content style in child theme

Tags: wordpress

I include bootstrap.css and style.css in my parent theme.

```
function my_scripts() { 
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');    
    wp_register_style('my-style', get_stylesheet_uri());        
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');      
    wp_enqueue_style('my-style');
    ....
}
```

In child theme I include parent style and after that the design crashed. When I see the source code in Firefox I see that parent style.css loads first then bootstrap.

```
function child_scripts() {  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css' );     
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_scripts', 15 );
```

How it is possible to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the same handle for multiple style files or they will overwrite one another. You are using "my-style" as a handle in both the parent and child functions file. Change those like below:

**Parent Theme**

```
function my_scripts() { 
    wp_register_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css');    
    wp_register_style('my-parent-style', get_stylesheet_uri());        
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap');      
    wp_enqueue_style('my-parent-style');
    ....
}
```

**Child Theme**

```
function child_scripts() {  
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-child-style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css' );     
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_scripts', 15 );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your child theme, replace your code with following codes in functions.php

```
function enqueue_parents_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parents_style' );
```